# Exclude some words from regular expression

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have function which inserts space after characters like : /  -

```
  Private Function formatColon(oldString As String) As String

  Dim reg As New RegExp: reg.Global = True: reg.Pattern = "(\D:|\D/|\D-)"
  Dim newString As String: newString = reg.Replace(oldString, "$1 ")
  formatColon = Replace(Replace(Replace(newString, ":  ", ": "), "/  ", "/ "), "-  ", "- ")

  End Function
```

The code excludes dates easily. I want to exclude some a particular strings like 'w/d' also.
Is there any way?

before `abc/abc/15/06/2017 ref:123243-11 ref-111 w/d`

after `abc/ abc/ 15/06/2017 ref: 123243-11 ref- 111 w/ d`

i want to exclude last w/d

Comment: Can you add before and after examples

Comment: before
**abc/abc/15/06/2017 ref:123243-11 ref-111 w/d**

after
**abc/ abc/ 15/06/2017 ref: 123243-11 ref- 111 w/ d**

i want to exclude last w/d

Comment: You may use `"(?!w/d)\D[:/-]"` and then `.Replace(oldString, "$& ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a `(?!w/d)` lookahead to avoid matching `w/d` with your pattern:

```
Dim oldString As String, newString As String
Dim reg As New RegExp
With reg
 .Global = True
 .Pattern = "(?!w/d)\D[:/-]"
End With
oldString = "abc/abc/15/06/2017 ref:123243-11 ref-111 w/d"
newString = reg.Replace(oldString, "$& ")
Debug.Print newString
```

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypuNUC/2).

**Pattern details**

- `(?!w/d)` - the location not followed with `w/d`
- `\D` - any non-digit char
- `[:/-]` - a `:`, `/` or `-` char.

The `$&` backreference refers to the whole match from the replacement pattern, no need to enclose the whole pattern with the capturing parentheses.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor... It worked Perfectly and my code is much better now

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.

```
^/(?!ignoreme$)(?!ignoreme2$)[a-z0-9]+$
```